# Android: Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata

I have looked some answer but related to firebase and live data not compatible or similar. My simple test application have nothing to do with firebase.

This is my gradle file in module level:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "room.exercise.com.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'

    //Design for room persistance storage
    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'
    /////

    //Design for live data
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
    //

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

This application just a simple test of Room and Live data which I load the data from database to recyclerView.. I know the Room database is working coz this was my first test.

The gradle file was sync without problem. The error occurred when I compile and run the application.

> Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Code:

```
public class RoomActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener {

private StudentListViewModel viewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_room);

    //RoomDatabase database = RoomDatabase.getDatabase(RoomActivity.this);
    //RoomDataInitializer.AddSampleDataAsync(database);

    //List<StudentEntity> students = database.studentDAO().getAllStudents();
    //Log.w("Room Activity", "Count = " + students.size());

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    final RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(new ArrayList<StudentEntity>(), this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(StudentListViewModel.class);

    viewModel.getStudentList().observe(RoomActivity.this, new Observer<List<StudentEntity>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<StudentEntity> studentEntities) {
            adapter.addItems(studentEntities);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: What is your android gradle plugin version?

Comment: the Gradle (in project level) is version 3.1.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just try this:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
```

instead of your versions.

I don't have explainable explanation for this solution, yet, I'll try.

This type of error occurs when one class is defined/brought in by 2 or more dependencies. (In your case it is `LifecycleBoundObserver`).

And this type of errors occur runtime only. They don't happen during gradle build/sync.

If this type of errors are occurring in firebase/android dependencies, mostly they maybe resolved by upgrading the version. (Or there might be an issue registered in issue tracker for the same.). In other cases, you might have to exclude modules/groups from dependencies bringing in redundant classes.